# Visual studio 2010 C# Use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, variables

i am making an application which will load and save settings in an xml file. i searched thru all those questions and answers and tried all those methods and i didn't find solution to my problem. here is the code:

```
private void DocumentToPrint_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        int x1 = 1;            
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("settings.xml");
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "coordinates"))
            {
                if (reader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    x1 = int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("tekst1x"));
                }

            }
        }
        reader.Close();

        var line1 = textBox1.Text;
        Font PrintFont = this.textBox1.Font;
        SolidBrush PrintBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(line1, PrintFont, PrintBrush, x1, 30, new StringFormat());
        PrintBrush.Dispose();
    }
```

so its always showing me

this error:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'x1' even i do have x1 assigned to 1.

on this line

`e.Graphics.DrawString(line1, PrintFont, PrintBrush, x1, 30, new StringFormat());`

any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance and best wishes.

**i edit the question and added the full code**

Comment: The code you showed compiles well. Could you provide the code that would result in this error?

Comment: User LINQ to XML would be easier for you

Comment: code looks healthy. Which line do you get error at?

Comment: If this very code still gives you an error, you could try `Clean` the solution and `Rebuild` it.

Comment: In the code you provided x1 is never read, so you shouldn't get that error. Can you post the actual line where you read it?

Comment: here is the code where i get error just bellow the previous code that i posted `e.Graphics.DrawString(line1, PrintFont, PrintBrush, x1, y1, new StringFormat());`

Comment: @UncontrolledCrowd this small code snippet shows nothing. Could you edit your answer and provide a small programm which would demostrate it all.

Comment: That should work. Are you sure this is all the code? Please edit the question and put the code there.

Comment: Yes @UncontrolledCrowd we need the full code to see what your missunderstanding is. Update your question with complete code.

Comment: Please make and edit and post the full method's code, there is probably a condition above the x1=1 assignment or something similar

Comment: @UncontrolledCrowd and this code does compile. As I've already said, clean and rebuild your solution or even reboot your IDE and try to compile again.

Comment: omg Konstantin Vasilcov :) well you were right. the simpliest solutions are always working :) i was trying to solve this problem for more than 1h and i just restarted the visual studio and the error dissapeared and its working :) thank you everyone for trying to help me. how can i mark this question as answered?

Comment: @UncontrolledCrowd I'll repost my comment as the answer. You may accept it if you wish

Comment: @UncontrolledCrowd you're welcome. One day I also spent time searching for this answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given code does compile well. It seems like an issue with the IDE. I suppose it'll be enough to `Clean` and`Rebuild` the solution. However if it does not help, you may try to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: certainly i will accept your answer cause it was the real one. thanks again to everyone for trying to help me. best wishes.